# Extract double from string

Tags: java

I have a string that is formatted like this `inputString = "!Circle(1.234)"`

How do I extract just the 1.234? I have tried:

```
double value = Double.parseDouble(inputString.(replaceAll("[^0-9]", "")));
```

but that would also remove the "."

Edit: Wonder if I have something like `inputString = "!Rectangle(1.2,1.3)"`

or

`input String = "!Triangle(1.1,1.2,1.3)"`

What do I need to do to extract the numbers first, before casting them as double?

Comment: Edit ur character set to also keep dots. `[^0-9\\.]`.

Comment: @Zabuzard There is no need to backslash-escape the dot inside a character class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
static Pattern DOUBLE_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("[-+]?[0-9]*\\.?[0-9]+([eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?");

public static double[] extractDoubles(String input) {
    return DOUBLE_PATTERN.matcher(input).results()
        .mapToDouble(m -> Double.parseDouble(m.group()))
        .toArray();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "!Triangle(1.1,1.2,1.3)";
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(extractDoubles(input)));
}
```

output:

```
[1.1, 1.2, 1.3]
```

Answer (score 5):

Exclude dot from your regex.

```
double value = Double.parseDouble(inputString.replaceAll("[^0-9.]", ""));
```

Comment: one more question: if I have something like {!Rectangle(1.2,1.3)}, how would I go about separating those numbers? Should I do split(",")?

Comment: There is no reason to backslash-escape the dot inside the character class.

Comment: @DavidConrad updated

Comment: @AdrianTran I am trying to find a quick solution for this "rectangle" case, but I cannot do it fast. 
It looks like it requires a more complex regex.

Comment: `split(",\\s*")` would do, eats also blanks after comma.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem correctly, your input string is like the following:

```
!Circle(1.234)
```

or even

```
{!Rectangle(1.2,1.3)}
```

You could "gather" all the numbers in your input string. For that you'd typically need a regular expression.

But I guess you're trying to write something that acts like an interpreter or something. In that case you'd need to write a state machine, that interprets (character for character) the whole input. That a way more complex thing to do.